# Postfix aliases warning

Tags: postfix

I want to forward emails sent to `user@example.com` to `john@example.com` and `bob@example.com`.  For that, I have to configured the `/etc/aliases` file, which contains:

```
# See man 5 aliases for format
postmaster:    root
user: john, bob
```

However, when I run `postmap /etc/aliases`, I get this warning:

```
postmap: warning: /etc/aliases, line 2: record is in "key: value" format; is this an alias file?
postmap: warning: /etc/aliases, line 3: record is in "key: value" format; is this an alias file?
```

How to I resolve it?  Am I doing something wrong?

Output of `cat /etc/postfix/main.cf | grep alias` is

```sh
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
```

Answer (score 4):

You're meant to run `newaliases` to update the alias database, not `postmap`.

Comment: Oh, my bad.  Thank you for helping out.  It seems to be working now!